# xlwings gives a traceback error when creating a new workbook

Tags: python, excel, macos, xlwings, excel-2016

I just installed xlwings on MacOS 10.10.2. It runs for python 2.7 but I cannot get it to run with 3.4. I tried both the pip and the conda installation.

On IDLE 3.4 I cannot even import xlwings. I get an error saying that the module does not exist.

On IDLE 2.7, I can import xlwings, but when I run

```
>>> wd = Workbook()
```

I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    wd = Workbook()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlwings/main.py", line 141, in __init__
    self.xl_app, self.xl_workbook = xlplatform.new_workbook()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 117, in new_workbook
    xl_workbook = xl_app.make(new=kw.workbook)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py", line 462, in __call__
    return self.AS_appdata.target().event(self._code, params, atts, codecs=self.AS_appdata).send(timeout, sendflags)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/aeosa/aem/__init__.py", line 189, in event
    codecs or self._codecs, self._createproc, self._sendproc)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/aeosa/aem/aemsend.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.AEM_event.setparam(key, codecs.pack(value))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py", line 273, in pack
    raise ValueError("Unknown Keyword: k.%s" % data.AS_name)
ValueError: Unknown Keyword: k.workbook
```

I'm completely stuck... I have both versions of Excel, 2011 and 2016. Excel 2016 is my default application. I don't know if that has an effect on xlwings.

Answer (score 0):

Support for Mac Excel 2016 is currently in the making, see this [issue](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/170). Same for being able to select from various installation, see [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/169).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped. I got it running now :)

Comment: This has now been released with v0.3.6